# Is there a standardized way of managing windows in Qt applications?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am in the search of a best practice or a design pattern to manage a Qt application's windows.

Let me explain what I mean. Say that I have an application that has some windows(A,B,C) and I have needs like opening a `window A` within `window B` and ensure that a new `window A` instance is created with valid parameters every time it is called and lastly when need to show window C bring existing instance in front if any else create a new instance.

Of course the real world application is much more complex and have more windows and restrictions so I don't want to spread my window management operations all over the code and I keep them in a static `WindowManager` class. (Actually this class is a singleton but I am considering to change it into a static class)

WindowManager class holds a (private)`QSharedPointer` for each window in the system so I can easily manipulate all windows from anywhere in the code. When I need to show `window X` I just call `WindowManager::showX(params)` and all the checks and initialization takes place in that code. Also I have methods like `WindowManager::minimizeX()` to handle some logic, show a system tray message and then minimize the window.

Is this a common need, and is there a general pattern to solve the problem? How do you people manage your applications' windows? Is what I did (static WindowManager class) acceptable?

---

**Edit:** The application is an system tray application so there is no parent child relationship between windows; instead they are all independent from each other and generally  user invokes any window by a (global)hotkey. However there are a few case that within a window I need to open another one but still they cannot be parent and child.

Comment: Can't say I've written anything as convoluted as this.  Typically, a main window with a variety of dialogs, modal or not as needed.  The code for handling a particular window goes into the class for that window.  If that window/dialog requires another dialog, it manages the setup of said dialog, but the logic is all in the class for the secondary dialog.  Is there something that prevents you from using that model?

Comment: Usually parents set up their children. Create child widget, configure it, bring it up. If there is a main window, that main window often takes care of many of the secondary windows. Don't see that one can factor out that much code into a separate class dedicated to window creation and management and that'd be good design (singletons almost never are).

Comment: @casualcoder : actually my application resides at system tray at most of its time and user triggers different windows by different (global)hotkeys and there is no parent-child relationship between the windows. A window can be called within another window or opened by a hotkey. That leads me have such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this is a though question to a simple day by day problem since there aren't any answers yet? this is too long for a comment so i'll post it as answer, still hoping for someone else to post the ultimate general enlightenment pattern, though ;) i wish i had a general pattern that'd fit all the time.

anyway, i would not put everything into the WindowManager "singleton" since it creates very strong coupling between it and all windows. this class might become very big since it contains all the complex rules (you said "real world app" - imagine 100 windows handled in a single class..). it might become hard to test and error prone since changes in one part might unintentionally influence other parts (imagine a bool used for five windows.. flip it and it might work for four, while one starts to act strangely). and one day it might keep you from reusing certain windows somewhere else (like in another program, or just in another part of the same program) since they need the WindowManager class, which in turn needs all other windows, so you can't move this one window somewhere else because it'd drag all the other windows along.

i'd try to create logical groups of windows and try to handle their interaction with several smaller controllers. maybe you might want to look into the MVC pattern. have the controllers decide how to manipulate the models and what views to show depending on user input.